# UIAlertView in viewDidLoad of RootViewController suddenly not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I've had a program that's been working well for a few years. Suddenly, when I upgrade to iOS 7, it no longer works. I am putting up a UIAlertView (a password dialog) in my RootViewController inside the UIAlertView. The UIAlertView shows up, but the UITextField in it does not. Any clue as to why this suddenly wouldn't work?

Abbreviated code:

```
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Some initialization

   if (!firstTimeInit) {
     alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Password",
                                                             @"Password") 
                                   message:NSLocalizedString(@"EnterPassword",
                                                             @"EnterPassword") 
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
     alert.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 300, 260);

     UITextField *myTextField =
         [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32.0f, 75.0f,
                                                       220.0f, 28.0f)];
     myTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Password", @"Password");

     [myTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
     [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
     [myTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
     myTextField.tag = 11;
     [alert addSubview:myTextField];
     CGAffineTransform myTransform =
         CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 75.0);
     [alert setTransform:myTransform];

     [prefs retain];
     [alert show];
     [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code,, and the alert came up for me, although the text field didn't appear in it. Are you sure that you're making it past the if test?

Comment: Sorry - yes - you're exactly correct, rdelmar. Alert view shows up - but text field is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` text field.

```
UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Password",
                                                         @"Password") 
                               message:NSLocalizedString(@"EnterPassword",
                                                         @"EnterPassword")];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
```

In your delegate method do something like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
    didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSString *password = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
  // Whatever password processing.

}
```

Adding subviews to a `UIAlertView` is not supported by UIKit, so you should use the supported way of doing this instead :)

Comment: Thanks - I don't know that this explains the UIAlertView not even coming up, though...

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your alertview code to viewWillAppear.  UI is not necessarily initialized in viewDidLoad.